# Juoyter Notebook - 500: Internal Server Error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, medium.com-publishing-api

I uninstalled jupyter notebook 7.1.2 and installed a lower version (6.4) due to some compatibility issues with 7+ versions but I couldn't open saved and new notebook after the downgrade. I have upgraded the nbconverts and other stuff. I keep having 500:Internal Server Error. How do I fix this please?